# PHP website without mysql

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I am currently  working on an existing website that lists products, there are currently a little over 500 products.

The website has a text file for every product and I want to make a search option, thinking of reading all the text files and create an xml document with the values once a day that can be searched.

The client indicated that they wanted to add products and is used to add them using the text files. There might be over 5000 products in the future so I think it's best to do this with mysql. This means importing the current products and create a crud page for products.

Does anyone have experience with a PHP website that does not use MySQL? Is it possible to keep adding text files and just index them once a day even if it would mean having over 5000 products?

Comment: If you care about I/O writes you will move to MySQL.

Comment: You're completely correct - text files for every product is the wrong way to go, and MySQL is absolutely the best way to go for this.

Comment: Possible? Yes. Practical? Not even remotely. Tell your client that the cost up front for building the site will be more but the cost down the road will be significantly less. The maintenance of the site and the products even at 500 will be a lot easier with a database implementation, at 5000 using a text file would be a nightmare and not really allow for any customisation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

5000 seems like an amount that's still managable to index with a daily cron job. As long as you don't plan on searching them real-time, it should work. It's not ideal, but it would work.

Comment: I will create an admin page that creates an xml file from the data in the text files so when the user changes something they can update the xml file. Hope that this will work for now as I am not sure how many searches will be performed in a day. The page can be changed easily to import the test file data in a database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very much possible, **NOT plausible** that you use files for these type of transactions.

It is also better to use XML instead of normal TXTs for the job. 5000 products with what kind of data associated to them might create problems in future.

## PS

Why not MySQL?

Comment: Client is used to provide product data using the text files. I will put them in an xml file and search that file. If this is no longer possible than most of the script can be used to insert the text file data in a database. When user changes text files than running the script can delete all data and re insert text files info again.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql was made because file based databases are slow and inaccurate.

Just use mysql. If you want to keep your old txt based database, just build an easy script that will import each file one by one and create corresponding tables in your sql database.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I will go with importing text file info into xml when the admin user chooses to do so (when they change something in the text files). If this cannot be done anymore than the information can be inserted in a database, small changes in the script can do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, however if this is a anything more than simply an online catalog, then managing transaction integrity is *horrendously* difficult - and that you're even asking the question implies that you are not in a good position to implement the kind of controls required. And as you've already discovered, it doesn't make for easy searching (BTW: mysql's fulltext indexing is a very blunt instrument - it's not a huge amount of effort to implement an effective search engine yourself - or there are excellent ones available off-the-shelf, e.g. [mnogosearch](http://www.mnogosearch.org/))

(as a conicdental point, why XML? It makes managing the data much more complicated than it needs to be)

> and create a crud page for products

Why? If the client wants to maintain the data via file uploads and you already need to port the data, then just use the same interface - *where* the data is stored is not relevant just now.

If there are issues with hosting+mysql, then using SQLite gives most of the benefits (although it wion't scale as well).

Comment: I am tempted to write a script that generates an xml file from all the text files. That will be used to search. The same xml generator and search script can easily be converted to put data in the database and search that database. All data will be deleted and all text files info will be inserted whenever the user chooses to update.